# better structuring the Java code

Tags: java, android, generics, polymorphism, refactoring

I have written this piece of code for an assignment and I want it to be well-factored. Basically, this is part of a simple old-school calculator which is to perform addition, subtraction, multiplication, division (when performing division, the reminder should always be shown). We are required to have separate classes for each operation (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division but I have introduced one more - reminder). Do you have any advice or do you see some gaps in my understanding of the concept of Java generics?

```
public class Logic 
       implements LogicInterface {

    private final int ADDITION = 1;
    private final int SUBTRACTION = 2;
    private final int MULTIPLICATION = 3;
    private final int DIVISION = 4;

    /**
     * Reference to the Activity output.
     */
    protected ActivityInterface mOut;

    /**
     * Constructor initializes the field.
     */
    public Logic(ActivityInterface out){
        mOut = out;
    }

    /**
     * Perform the @a operation on @a argumentOne and @a argumentTwo.
     */
    public void process(int argumentOne,
                        int argumentTwo,
                        int operation){

        OperationsInterface operationsInterface =null;

        if(operation==ADDITION)
        {
            operationsInterface = new Add();
        }
        else if(operation==SUBTRACTION)
        {
            operationsInterface = new Subtract();
        }
        else if(operation==MULTIPLICATION)
        {
            operationsInterface = new Multiply();
        }
        else
        {
            operationsInterface = new Divide();
        }

    if(argumentTwo==0 && operation == DIVISION) {
        mOut.print("You cannot divide by zero!");
    }
    else {
        try {
            //get the result
            int result = operationsInterface.process(argumentOne, argumentTwo);
            mOut.print(String.valueOf(result));

            //add the reminder to the output in case we are performing division
            if (operation == DIVISION) {
                operationsInterface = new Reminder();
                mOut.print(result + " R: " + String.valueOf(operationsInterface.process(argumentOne, argumentTwo)));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            mOut.print("Something went wrong!");
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Change `ADD` etc into an enum, and implement the operator-specific logic as methods on the enum.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what this has to do with generics.

As from the code review point of view:

1. You should always ask yourself how easy it is to change your code when you need to extend some functionality. In your case, suppose you want to add another operator. You would need to add a constant and add another if/else case, and maybe some other logic. I would suggest to have a map from operator constants to operating classes, or use an enum for that; then you only need to initialize it once and save the if/else cases.
2. Consider having different `Add` classes, one that does the simple addition, and another that prints out something. If you want to exchange them, you need to change the `new Add()` part, but then you cannot have two calculators, one with the simple Add and another with the extended one. Therefore, it is good practice to use `new` in some kind of factory method that can be easily overridden, e.g. `protected OperationInterface createAdd() {return new Add();}`. Then you can subclass your calculator and override `createAdd()`. Same holds for all other operators, of course.
3. Your `OperationInterface` seems to return an `int`. I do not think it works for division. Should be at least a `double`.
4. I would see the `Reminder` as a subclass of `Divide`. At least the logic is related to division operations only and should be therefore located in the `Divide` class or some subclass of it.

Answer (score 0):

The following might give you an idea how you might refactor your class design:

1. Define an interface like the followin:

   ```
   public interface LogicInterface<T extends Number> {
       T calculate(T operand1, T operand2);
   }
   ```
2. Implement this interface for your operations:

   ```
   public class Addition implements LogicInterface<Integer> {
       public Integer calculate(Integer operand1, Integer operand2) {
           return operand1.intValue() + operand2.intValue();
      }
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   public class Division implements LogicInterface<Integer> {
       public Integer calculate(Integer operand1, Integer operand2) {
           if (operand2 == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

           return operand1.intValue() / operand2.intValue();
       }
   }
   ```

   etc.
3. Implement a factory:

   ```
   public class CalculatorFactory {
       public enum CalculatorType {
           ADD, SUBTRACT, MULTIPLY, DIVIDE, MODULO;  // etc
       }

       public static LogicInterface<Integer> getOperator(CalculatorType type) {
           switch (type) {
               case ADD: return new Addition();
               case DIVIDE: return new Division();
               // etc

               default: throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Operation type not supported");
           }
      }
   }
   ```
4. User it as follows:

   ```
   public class CalculatorTest {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           LogicInterface<Integer> add =   CalculatorFactory.getOperator(CalculatorType.ADD);
           System.out.println("Sum of 1 and 2: " + add.calculate(14, 16));
       }

   }
   ```

So you can add more operators by just implementing the interface as you need and you have only to change the factory class. The rest should never be changed.

Hope it gives you an idea how you implement.